# Is this question scoped enough to reopen from duplicate that only answers part?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I've closed following question as duplicate and indeed OP disagrees with it. I feel that question is a bit too broad so I don't think re-open is right at this point... Is my assessment of the scope of the question is correct or it is indeed well scoped for SO?

[how does instantiation work with .net attributes? how could a thread safety issue be occurring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885795/how-does-instantiation-work-with-net-attributes-how-could-a-thread-safety-issu)?
Partial content of the question:

> 1) How are custom attributes instantiated? When is the constructor called?
>
> 2) In a multi threaded environment (like on a web server), how is an attribute handled? Who holds the reference to the object?
>
> 3) Is it possible then, that the same object could be called concurrently? What are some strategies to handle concurrency in .Net attributes? My instinct is to fix the thread safety issue with the libraries (they are open source), if there is one, but are there other approaches?
>
> EDIT: This is different from the linked question, in that I'm trying to understand the behavior of attributes in a multi-threaded server environment.

Duplicate I picked - [When are Attribute instances created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196647/when-are-attribute-instances-created) only covers some of the points.

Comment: It's been closed as a duplicate. The linked duplicate is 10 years old, and the answers are out of date - there have been new features added to the language since (documentation linked in an edit to the question.

Now he's saying the question is too broad, not a duplicate. Respectfully to Alexei, and the time he's taken to moderate here, but I feel as the goalposts are being moved.

Comment: Alexei said that there were too many questions in the question, at the time of closing @scuba. No goalposts are being moved. The duplicate is an attempt to be partially helpful rather that not at all helpful.

Comment: It is indeed far too broad, goalposts or not. @Scuba, just scope the linked question to the questions that are covered by the duplicate and ask a new question for each of the remaining questions you have. You get your answers, we get a clean, orderly site. Win win.